# Regex for Java split involving spaces and double quotations

Tags: java, regex, split

What expression would I use to split a string by either spaces or material within double quotes (quotes are to be included in the string)?

The spaces are splitting out from within the double quotes and I don't want those spaces split, just spaces outside the quotes.

I do have success with spaces and double-quotes just not for spaces inside the double-quotes. The split is parsing those blanks into substrings.

This is Java regex. For example, this works ok, but "this does not"

Thank You 
Dennis

Comment: You are walking into the territory of proper scanners. Do study a bit about lexical analysers and write a simple one for your use case. RegEx may not be able to do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Split on the following regex:

```
\s*"[^"]*"\s*|\s+
```

The first alternative (before the "|") contains:

- a sequence of spaces (actually also *Tab* on *\n*), possibly empty,
- a double quote (opening),
- a sequence of chars other than a double quote,
- another double quote (closing),
- another sequence of spaces.

The second alternative (after the "|") contains just a non-empty sequence of spaces.

Both surrounding `\s*` in the first alternative are to prevent a string like
`"xxx yyy"` from treating like 3 **separate** splitting tokens (a space before,
the quoted string and a space after).

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/76jaZb/1,
but since this pattern is for **splitting** (not matching) actually look
at parts of the source string **between** the matches.